# gulp watch on gulpfile.js itself

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'd like to not only have `gulp watch` watch for changes to specified files, but also to the gulpfile.js itself. Notably, I'm using [Laravel and its Elixir](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir) asset management tool, which wraps Gulp.

I came across [this link](http://codepen.io/ScavaJripter/post/how-to-watch-the-same-gulpfile-js-with-gulp) which seems to be exactly what I need but when I implement it and then type either `gulp watch` or `gulp` and then make changes to my gulpfile those changes aren't reflected.

I'm pretty sure I need to add something to the elixir but not sure what. I have the following for bower but probably need something similar for watch.

Here's the relevant contents of my gulpfile:

```
/*gulpfile.js*/
gulp.slurped = false; // step 1

gulp.task("watch", function(){

    if(!gulp.slurped){ // step 2
        gulp.watch("gulpfile.js", ["default"]);
        //gulp.watch("etc...");
        gulp.slurped = true; // step 3
    }

});

gulp.task("default", ["some-task", "another-task", "watch"]);

gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return bower();
});

elixir(function(mix) {
  // Run bower install
  mix.task('bower');
  //mix.task('default'); //uncommenting this causes an error when running "gulp"
  //mix.task('watch'); //uncommenting this causes an error when running "gulp"

  // all other elixir.mix tasks...
  mix.copy('resources/assets/js/**', 'public/js');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gulper` is one possible answer: https://github.com/anatoo/gulper

So instead of running `gulp watch` you can run `gulper watch`